# Customizando botão enviar arquivo do Contact Form 7 wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Tenho um formulário em contact form 7, do wordpress, que preciso mudar o botão de anexar aquivos, hoje ele é assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que os botões fiquem assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei de tudo e nada!!!
Se alguém precisar acessa a página teste é essa [aqui](http://premioeducacao.ramosdesignservidor.com.br/inscricao/#ficha-rj)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode resolver esse problema em dois passos.

1. Criar o CSS dos `inputs`
   Uma técnica simples que utiliza HTML e CSS consiste em apontar o atributo `for` de um `label` para o `input` de seleção de arquivo (que estará oculto). Quando o usuário clicar no `label`, será como clicar no `input` de arquivo. Um exemplo:

   ```
   input[type='file'] {
       display: none
   }

   label {
       background-color: #fdd31d;
       color: #000;
       cursor: pointer;
       margin: 10px;
       padding: 6px 20px;
       display: table;
   }

   <label for='anexo-1'>Anexo 1</label>
   <input id='anexo-1' type='file'>
   <label for='anexo-2'>Anexo 2</label>
   <input id='anexo-2' type='file'>
   <label for='anexo-3'>Anexo 3</label>
   <input id='anexo-3' type='file'>
   ```

https://jsfiddle.net/Darlei_Zillmer/65s18g4v/

2. Atribuir os ids e classes no Formulário do Contact Form 7:

   ```
   <label for='anexo1'>Anexo 1</label>
   [file file-1 id:anexo1]
   <label for='anexo2'>Anexo 2</label>
   [file file-2 id:anexo2]
   <label for='anexo3'>Anexo 3</label>
   [file file-3 id:anexo3]
   ```

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado!!!

Answer (score 1):

Com base na ajuda do Darlei, consegui fazer! Segue a solução:

```
 .styled-select #sexo{

        background: url(icone-seta-premio.png) no-repeat;
        height: 45px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 999;
        background-position: center center;
        background-position-x: 110px;
        background-color: #f7f7f7;
        border: 1px solid #eee;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 16px;
        height: 37px;

    }

    .styled-select {
        height: 45px;


    }
```

Obrigado pela atenção e ajuda!!!